# Javascript retrieve what in the tag using class attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im working on a Asp.net MVc application to create a scheduler application for workers.

The schedule is auto-generate using a JavaScript library called: Dhtmlx Scheduler.
upon populating the data, it creates some Html and places the content.

I would like to retrieve the content and was wondering if it's possible by obtaining the info from its class.

Pic for reference:
[image]

I am trying to retrieve the "Abel Toribio" so i can do a reverse search in my database for his name and eventually display a tooltip over that td with further information about the person.

So far I have tried:

```
var engName = document.getElementsByClassName("dhx_matrix_scell");
alert(engName[0].getData());
alert(engName[0].getContent());
alert(engName[0].getText());
alert(engName[0].getValue());
```

They all seem to give me undefined.
Thanks!

Comment: what data you are trying to access?

Comment: What? Why post a picture *when you can post the markup from the browser source*? Also, you're feeling around for `element.textContent()`.

Comment: Have you tried `engName[0].innerHTML` as suggested by [the documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)?

Comment: That's because the object `engName` is an array and does not have functions you can call.

Comment: As mentioned above im trying to retrieve what is in the tag, which as the attribute class. (Abel Toribio)

I'll try that thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `engName[0].innerHTML` - for contents inside the tag 'html'.
- `engName[0].outerHTML` - for contents inside the tag wrapped in the tag.
- `engName[0].textContent` - for contents inside the tag 'text'.

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged  **jquery** as well,for tooltip purpose, you can write `mouseover` event using **jquery** this way :

```
$(".dhx_matrix_scell").on("mouseover",function(){

alert($(this).text());

// do something here

});
```

if you want to get all, you can get them like this:

```
$.each(".dhx_matrix_scell",function(){


alert($(this).text());

});
```

Comment: Thanks this will help in the future!!

Comment: This works!
is there a way to display the information other then using a alert()?